# STM32F401 Nucleo SPI Clock issue, using STM32CubeF4

Tags: c, stm32, spi

STM32F401RE --> CortexM4
I am using SPI1 with HAL low level drivers, STM32CubeF4.
I have used the following SPI configuration:-

```
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi;
hspi.Instance=SPI1;
hspi.Init.Mode=SPI_MODE_MASTER;
hspi.Init.Direction=SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
hspi.Init.DataSize=SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi.Init.CLKPolarity=SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
hspi.Init.CLKPhase=SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi.Init.NSS=SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi.Init.BaudRatePrescaler=SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
hspi.Init.FirstBit=SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi.Init.TIMode=SPI_TIMODE_ENABLED;
hspi.Init.CRCCalculation=SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLED;
hspi.Init.CRCPolynomial=0;
HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi);
```

After sending some bytes on MOSI. On logic analyzer, I see clock and MOSI data are mismatched. 
This is a very zoomed in pic, If required I can send the whole logic analyzer file.

[image]

For read and write, I am using 
HAL_spi_transmit(&hspi, Byte, 1, 5);
HAL_spi_Receive(&hspi, Byte, 1, 5);

I did the almost same spi configuration with stm32l151rct6a, using std periph library and it is working.

Question: Why is the clock not synchronised with MOSI?

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that there is just a command flow like

```
SET_SCK_HIGH();
SET_MOSI_HIGH();
```

in the master, and thus the effects are visible at a slightly different time.

Comment: uh! No, I used HAL_spi_transmit(&hspi, Byte, 1, 5);, this API transmits 1 Byte over MOSI, hspi is the config structure as defined. The problem is, it is random, cause sometimes they do get synchronised. But, mostly if I transmit 0x31, the slave board receives 0x73 or 0x63 sometimes.

Comment: The problem seems to me, is configuration of SPI I did. But, as of now I have not found the solution.

Comment: @Ishmeet Then we have a different imagination about what "synchronized" means. My point is, those signals on't necessarily have to ocur at exactly the same time. Even if you use `HAL_spi_transmit()`, this function internally does things I wrote about, and that's fine. But there may be parameters such the byte dire first or MSB first) and the SPI mode which refers to which of 0 or 1 is the default value of SCK and on which edge the data is actually transferred.